# XMLHttpRequest takes very long only in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, ajax, performance, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest

We have recently noticed an issue where a common page on our site temporarily freezes when navigated to from Internet Explorer with the message "This web page is not responding due to a long running script".

After investigating, I can see that it is caused by an AJAX XMLHttpRequest that is taking 30 - 45 seconds to complete. Normally when there are performance issues with our AJAX calls like this, the long wait time is during the wait for the server's response. But here, it is the wait to create the request and send it that is taking so long:

[image: Long Start Time]

Note that there are no issues with this request in Google Chrome at all, it only takes 200ms:

[image: Quick in Chrome]

These results are consistent on every page refresh. Note also that this is not a large request nor a large response. The request body is actually empty:

[image: Empty Request]

and the response is quite small:

[image]

I figured since the problem appears to be client-side, there must be something off with our scripts, but we use the same generic function for all of our AJAX calls and don't have this problem with anything else:

```
JSONRequest: function (url, type, data, success, error) {
        var customError = function (er) {
            console.log(er);
        }
        if (error !== 'undefined' && error != null)
            customError = error;
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: type,
            cache: false,
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: success,
            error: customError
        });
    },
```

I am quite puzzled here. Is this simply a matter of "Avoid IE", or is there something I am missing? 30+ seconds to create a small request and send it seems absurdly long, especially when it is fast in Chrome. What gives?

*Note that I am testing with IE 11.

Comment: Perhaps a DNS lookup is slow or a firewall takes some time to check the connection. Did you try to capture the actual network traffic and compare IE with Chrome?

Comment: Are you using Type : HEAD in your request? If yes than it can be the cause for the issue. If possible for you than you can you can use Type : GET or POST may help to solve this issue for IE. The status of XMLHttpRequest for HEAD requests is getting stuck in state 2 until the connection is closed, then it goes to 4.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, a line of JQuery that unchecks all check boxes in a list of them was causing the issue:

```
$('.list-check-buttons.check-button.only-button input:checkbox').prop('checked', false)
```

I verified this by stepping through in the Chrome Debugger and also removing this line resolved the issue for the most part. (It turns out we didn't need this line as the same logic was also being handled in another place which strangely enough was not causing performance issues.)